# Invalid PE file error on Unity while running pdb2mdb.exe

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to generate ".mdb" file from my ".pdb" file in order to set up a debugging session for the DLL. But I am receiving "BadImageFormatException: Invalid PE file" on pdb2mdb.exe file.

Unity doc for problem related: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html

Here is command I am running:

```
"D:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\pdb2mdb.exe" "D:\Projects\UnityXGame\UnityXGame.Games\UnityXGame.Sandbox\Assets\UnityXGame.Unity.Common.pdb"
```

This reference file works on Unity 5 correctly. I can call classes and their instances.

I am receiving following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Invalid PE file
>   File name:
>   'D:\Projects\UnityXGame\UnityXGame.Games\UnityXGame.Sandbox\Assets\UnityXGame.Unity.Common.pdb'
>   ---> Mono.Cecil.Binary.ImageFormatException: Invali d PE File Signature    at Mono.Cecil.Binary.ImageReader.VisitDOSHeader(DOSHeader
>   header)    at Mono.Cecil.Binary.Image.Accept(IBinaryVisitor visitor)
>   at Mono.Cecil.Binary.ImageReader.Read(String file)    at
>   Mono.Cecil.Binary.ImageReader.Read(String file)    at
>   Mono.Cecil.AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly(String file)    at
>   Pdb2Mdb.Driver.Main(String[] args)

Is there any idea there I can fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter passed to the pdb2mdb should be assembly file (.exe or .dll) not the .pdb file. The usage of the tool is not very well explained on the Unity documentation page but [here are  some tips on how to use it](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/294195/pdb2mdb-usage-error-from-command-line.html)

Comment: Thanks. I just changed my build script and it works great now!. That's true, it does not make any sense to give .pdb file as input from first instance :)